# How to add a loading animation when loading a promise object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JavaScript and jQuery to write my website but I get the following problem.

I want to sleep the thread and display a loading animation only until the promise object is completely loaded into my website.

And I don't know how to do that, Can anyone help?

---

@A.Wolff
Since I have this problem when I am using the PDF.JS plugin. And I am trying to declare a self-defined class on top of it.

Following is my self-defined class

```
function WhiteBoardPdf3(canvasContext,url){
this.canvasContext=canvasContext;
this.url=url;
this.pdfOriPromise=PDFJS.getDocument(url);
this.pdfPromise=Promise.cast(this.pdfOriPromise);
this.pdfDoc=null;
/*----Here is the problem------*/
this.pdfPromise.then(function getPdf(_pdfDoc){
    this.pdfDoc=_pdfDoc
});
/*----------------------------*/
this.pageNum=1;
this.scale=1;
this.renderPage(1);
}
WhiteBoardPdf3.prototype.getPdfPromise=function(){
return this.pdfPromise;
}
WhiteBoardPdf3.prototype.renderPage=function(){
var num=this.pageNum;
var scale=this.scale;
var canvasContext=this.canvasContext;
var canvas=canvasContext.canvas;
var canvasClassName=canvas.className;
var allCanvas=document.getElementsByClassName(canvasClassName);
var canvasContainer=document.getElementById("whiteBoardLayerContainer");
this.pdfPromise.then(function getPdf(_pdfDoc){
    _pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page){
        var viewport=page.getViewport(scale);
        for(var i=0;i<allCanvas.length;i++){
            allCanvas[i].height=viewport.height;
            allCanvas[i].width=viewport.width;
        }
        canvasContainer.style.width=viewport.width+'px';
        var renderContext={
            canvasContext: canvasContext,
            viewport: viewport
        }
        page.render(renderContext);
    });
});
}
WhiteBoardPdf3.prototype.getPdfNumOfPages=function(){
this.pdfDoc.numPages;
}
```

And the PDFJS.getDocument(url) will return a promise object.

However, the problem is that when I construct this class and call the getPdfNumOfPages() function in the main program. I notice that the program will call the getPdfNumOfPages() function before the "pdfDoc"(promise object) is finish loading. So I want to sleep the thread and display the loading animation before the promise object is finish loading. So as to the  getPdfNumOfPages() function will run after the "pdfDoc" is loaded.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you're currently using and where the specific problem is in that code?

Comment: Where are you stuck because basically there is nothing hard in the fact to show a loading animation when setting promise and remove it when promise is completed, using e.g `always()` callback

Comment: @GeorgeStocker The code I'm currently using is added in the question, thank you.

Comment: @A.Wolff The description for where I am stuck is added in the question, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

As indicated in comments (*thanks A. Wolff and Frédéric Hamidi*), this solution is better:

```
//
// launch loader
// before
//

// make xhr query
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
  url: 'your/action'
});

// call the always promise method, automatically invoked 
// when the $.ajax action is completed
jqxhr.always(function() {
 // stop loader in every situations (success or failure)
});
```

**Previous solving post solution below:**

*This solution is enought only if the xhr query is done without error.*

You can use `$.when`

> Description: Provides a way to execute callback functions based on one
>   or more objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous
>   events.

```
//
// set loader on here
// 
$.when($.ajax('/action/to/do')).then(function(response) {
 // reset your loader
 // action completed ;)
});
```

Comment: With this solution, the loader will not be dismissed if the AJAX request results in an error. `always()`, as A. Wolff suggests, would be a better fit. Also, `$.when()` is not necessary here, you can invoke `then()` or `always()` directly on the promise returned by `$.ajax()`.

Answer (score 1):

well you could show a image of loading on your page before sending a ajax request and hide it after a response is received .

**HTML CODE:**

```
<img name="loadingImage" id="loadingImg" src="http://www.ppimusic.ie/images/loading_anim.gif "  width="100px" height="100px" />



 $('#loadingImg').hide();
 $.ajax({
   url: "test.html",
   data: {data1:'smile'},
   beforeSend:function() {
       $('#loadingImg').show();
   },
   success:function(response) {
       $('#loadingImg').hide();
       //process the successful response 
   },
   error:function(response) {
       $('#loadingImg').hide();
       //process the error response 
   } 
});
```

Happy Coding:)